# Zeroclipboard multiple elements

Tags: jquery, click, popupwindow, zeroclipboard

I'm having trouble creating multiple Zeroclipboard instantiations in my code, with each instantiation launching a popup window after it is invoked.

```
<a class="xxx" href="popup.url.php" ><span >FRSDE3RD</a>
<a class="xxx" href="popup.url2.php" ><span >FRSDE3RD2</a>
<a class="xxx" href="popup.url3.php" ><span >FRSDE3RD3</a>
$(document).ready(function(){
    ZeroClipboard.setMoviePath( 'path/to/swf/ZeroClipboard.swf' );
    // setup single ZeroClipboard object for all our elements
    clip = new ZeroClipboard.Client();
    clip.setHandCursor( true );

    // assign a common mouseover function for all elements using jQuery
    $('a.xxx').mouseover( function() {
        // set the clip text to our innerHTML
        var url = $(this).attr("href");
        var code = $(this).children('span').html();
        clip.setText( $(this).children('span').html() );//this.innerHTML );

        clip.glue(this);
        clip.addEventListener('onMouseDown', function(){
            clip.reposition(this);
            clip.setText( code );
        });

        clip.addEventListener('onComplete', function(){ 
            clip.reposition(this);
            popUp(url);
        }); 


    });
});

function popUp(URL)
{
    day = new Date();
    id = day.getTime();
    eval("page" + id + " = window.open(URL, '" + id + "', 'toolbar=1,scrollbars=1,location=1,statusbar=1,menubar=1,resizable=1,width=1024,height=768,left = 328,top = 141');");
}
```

I succeed on generating the copy to clipboard functionality, but if I use either onMouseUp, onComplete events to trigger popup function, it either fire like 4-5 popups or doesn't fire at all.

P.S. I tried to adapt the solution from [How to load an Ajax response into clipboard using jQuery and ZeroClipboard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/890444/how-to-load-an-ajax-response-into-clipboard-using-jquery-and-zeroclipboard) instead of ajax call just copy to clipboard and on complete to lunch a popup ... as I said didn't worked for me.

What else I figured it out while having flashblocker enabled is that every time I rollover a CODE tag a new flash is being created on the same spot so this might be an explanation why I'm having 3-4 popup when I click it. If I rollover more, more popups come. Is there a way to stop the flash from creating on same spot or destroy on rollout?

Answer (score 14):

after more research I got to my solution to this problem:

```
$("a.xxx").each(function() {
  //Create a new clipboard client
  var clip = new ZeroClipboard.Client();
  clip.setHandCursor( true );

  //Glue the clipboard client to the last td in each row
  clip.glue(this);

  var url = $(this).attr("href");
  //Grab the text from the parent row of the icon
  var code = $(this).children('span').html();    
  clip.setText(code);

  //Add a complete event to let the user know the text was copied
  clip.addEventListener('complete', function(client, text) {
    //alert("Copied text to clipboard:\n" + text);
    popUp(url);
  });
});
```

this is the solution if anyone else will get stuck on this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try using http://www.steamdev.com/zclip/ it allows you direct access to jquery and you can use your own logic in the return statement.

include jquery.zclip.js
download and save ZeroClipboard.swf

Here is a snippet:

```
$(".class-to-copy").zclip({
    path: "assets/js/ZeroClipboard.swf",
    copy: function(){
        return $(this).attr("data-attribute-with-text-to-copy");
    }
});
```

Make sure you change the path of the swf.

Answer (score 0):

What Andrei C answered is outdated.
Just do it as follows.

```
<a id="test1" class="test" href="#"  data-clipboard-text="1">111</a>
<a id="test2" class="test" href="#"  data-clipboard-text="2">111</a>
<a id="test3" class="test" href="#"  data-clipboard-text="3">111</a>
<script src="js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="dist1/ZeroClipboard.js"></script>
<script>
var client = new ZeroClipboard( );
client.clip($(".test"));

client.on( "ready", function( readyEvent ) {
  client.on( "aftercopy", function( event ) {
    alert("Copied text to clipboard: " + event.data["text/plain"] );
  } );
});

</script>
```